# Freeze a mouseover fade

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image fade into another when on mouse over. The second image has image maps for links that the user will follow. Every time i try to click the map links the image fades back to the original first image. Here's my code so far. Help

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='../js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js'>

</script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("img.a").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});
});
</script>
<style>
div.fadehover {
    position: relative;
    }

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="fadehover">
<img src="../Background.jpg" alt="" class="a" usemap="#Map" border="0"/>
<img src="../optiontwo.jpg" alt="" class="b"/>
<map name="Map" id="Map" class="maps">
  <area shape="rect" coords="100,488,195,540" href="https://vimeo.com/lsufilmclub" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="87,433,202,489" href="http://www.youtube.com/user/LSUFilmClub" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="702,440,834,493" href="https://www.facebook.com/LSUFilmClub" />
  <area shape="rect" coords="711,493,805,562" href="https://twitter.com/LSUFilmClub" />
</map>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us a fiddle and explain it better?

Comment: Basically I have 2 images. The first fades into the second and the second has mapping of links on it. When I hover over the links the first image reappears. I want to stop that

Comment: For this, you need to show us a demo and we can say where you might have gone wrong. :)

Comment: http://lsufilmclub.com/test/ here is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to stop the element with 0 opacity from being clicked on. One solution might be this:

```
$('img.a').click(function(event) {
    if ($(this).css('opacity')==0) { event.preventDefault() };
});
```

However this still would block the click from happening to elements below it. Depending on how you have things set up, you could instead add an extra callback function to hide the element completely once it's faded out, so the click goes through it, something along these lines:

```
function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow", function () { $(this).hide(); });
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow", function () { $(this).hide(); });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your intent but in the code you gave us the image WITH the links (the image map) is getting faded out. I think you want:

```
$("img.b").hover(
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "0"}, "slow");
},
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({"opacity": "1"}, "slow");
});

img.a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;

    }

img.b {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
   z-index: 10;
    }
```

Comment: that makes it go backwards. http://lsufilmclub.com/test/ this is the solution im getting, I dont want the links to fade out